# Loading and Saving XML File into Listview

Tags: c#, xml

I have a little problem when loading my XML file into Listview.
It's not loading all the values and it's only load single nodes.
could you tell me what's the problem with my loop to load the values?
or any suggestion to make this better and working?

Someone suggested me to use JSON.net to make easier loading and saving into listview but can't find resources about it. so I just did xml because this is only what I know when it comes saving and load files.

Here's the xml file:

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Settings>
>   <title><![CDATA[Episode 1]]></title>
>   <duration><![CDATA[59.33]]></duration>
>   <resolution><![CDATA[1280x560]]></resolution>
>   <title><![CDATA[Episode 2]]></title>
>   <duration><![CDATA[01.04.25]]></duration>
>   <resolution><![CDATA[1280x560]]></resolution>
> </Settings>
> ```

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file = @"C:\Users\MARK\Desktop\__TEST\SAMPLE.xml";

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(file);
            XmlNodeList topM = doc.SelectNodes("Settings");

            LV.BeginUpdate();
            foreach (XmlElement element in topM)
            {
                ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem();

                XmlNodeList Title = element.GetElementsByTagName("title");
                for (int i = 0; i < Title.Count; i++)
                {
                    items.Text = Title[i].InnerText;
                }

                XmlNodeList Duration = element.GetElementsByTagName("duration");
                for (int i = 0; i < Duration.Count; i++)
                {
                    items.SubItems.Add(Duration[i].InnerText);
                }

                XmlNodeList Resolution = element.GetElementsByTagName("resolution");
                for (int i = 0; i < Resolution.Count; i++)
                {
                    items.SubItems.Add(Resolution[i].InnerText);
                }

                LV.Items.Add(items);
            }
            LV.EndUpdate();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file = @"C:\Users\MARK\Desktop\__TEST\SAMPLE.xml";

        using (XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            xml.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
            xml.WriteStartDocument();
            xml.WriteStartElement("Settings");

            foreach (ListViewItem i in LV.Items)
            {
                xml.WriteStartElement("title"); 
                xml.WriteCData(i.Text.ToString()); 
                xml.WriteEndElement();

                xml.WriteStartElement("duration"); 
                xml.WriteCData(i.SubItems[1].Text); 
                xml.WriteEndElement();
                
                xml.WriteStartElement("resolution"); 
                xml.WriteCData(i.SubItems[2].Text); 
                xml.WriteEndElement();
            }

            xml.WriteEndElement();
            xml.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }
```

Comment: for `resolution` and `duration` will loads all values, but for  `Title` no, you should concatenate titles, may be like : `items.Text += Title[i].InnerText;` and will be good xml if you use the structure : `<Settings><Setting><title> </title>...</Setting><Setting><title></title>...</Setting></Settings>` and loop for each setting in settings.

Comment: It's alright. I found another way to save and load using BinaryFormatter. 
Because I have a lot of data to save

Comment: But I might try your suggestion too by tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hours of searching and analyzing.
This is what I've found using BinaryFormatter.

This is might help others too :)

```
   private void SaveBinary(ListView lv)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            sfd.Filter = "*.bin|*.bin";
            sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ListViewItem[] items = new ListViewItem[lv.Items.Count];
                lv.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);
                // Serialize the items and save it to a file.
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(sfd.FileName))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    bf.Serialize(fs, items);
                }
                this.Text = "Data has been saved";
            }
        }
    }
    private void LoadBinary(ListView lv)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            ofd.Filter = "*.bin|*.bin";
            ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ListViewItem[] items = null;
                // Deserialize the items from the binary file.
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    items = (ListViewItem[])bf.Deserialize(fs);
                }

                lv.Items.Clear();
                lv.BeginUpdate();
                // Load the items into the listView1.Items collection.
                lv.Items.AddRange(items);
                lv.EndUpdate();
            }
            this.Text = "Data has been loaded";
        }
    }
```

source: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27293776/Load-and-save-the-content-of-a-listview-to-binary-file.html